# PHP7 IIS missing $_SERVER['DOCUMENTROOT']

Tags: php, iis, global-variables, missing-features

I have recently upgraded to PHP7.2.3 running on Windows10 IIS.

One thing that is missing is the **$_SERVER['DOCUMENTROOT']** variable. As I use this quite a lot in my web pages I depend on it being set.

Is there a php.ini line that governs the setting or how can I have this set? What are the alternatives?

Comment: It is `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: That variable is missing or is not set! All other $_SERVER vars seem to be set

Comment: You can see the output of [phpinfo][http://public-ftp.gumtreegully.com.au/uploads/phpinfo.pdf]

Comment: `if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])){
 $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] , 0 , -strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])+1);
}`

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?382603-_SERVER-DOCUMENT_ROOT-from-Apache-to-IIS-HELP!

Comment: You can see the output of [phpinfo()](http://public-ftp.gumtreegully.com.au/uploads/phpinfo.pdf)

Comment: And $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] is also not defined!

Comment: Have you tried the result from `__DIR__` ? Try `print __DIR__;` somewhere and see what you get. According to the documentation, it should be the path of the current script, without relying on the server to cooperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that in IIS-10 I had to add "FastCGI settings" module the path to php_cgi.exe. After adding the path the variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is set automatically again by the system